# ClassNotFoundException when reading object from ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, objectinputstream

I am pretty new to Spring MVC and webapps in general. I have been trying to make a project that reads an object through a socket's output stream. When I try the socket connection and my object in a separate project with just a simple main class, `inputStream.readObject()` works out and reads out the `TradeRecord`. But when I combine it in my test Springmvc project, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` for my TradeRecord.

Part of my controller.java class:

```
public void readRecord(){
    try {
        Socket socket = connectServer();
        ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        while (true) {
            TradeRecord rec = (TradeRecord) inputStream.readObject();
            System.out.println(inputStream.readObject());
        }
    } catch (SocketException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

TradeRecord class which is copied directly from the person sending the object:

```
package models;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class TradeRecord implements Serializable
{
    public static final int STATUS = 0;
    ...
    public String TradeID;
    public char OrdStatus;
    public char TimeInForce;
    ...

    public int timeOnList = 0;
    public String venueID = "";
    public String sourceID = "";
    public String errMsg = "";
}
```

dispatcher:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="controllers"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/bootstrap/**" location="/bootstrap/" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TradeRecord
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:626)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
```

I have tried to make the TradeRecord into a jar and manually adding it to my external libraries, under the lib of my WEB-INF, and under the lib in Tomcat (in separate occasions). I also tried to put the POJO under the base controllers package just to see if it can be found there but none of it worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

edit* I am currently using Intellij IDEA 2017.1.1 and building with maven.

Comment: How come java.lang.ClassNotFoundException does not contain package name `models` for your class.

Comment: If you copy a class `TradeRecord` to another package models, you create another, different class, with a different name: `models.TradeRecord`. Using serialization is already a bad idea, but using it by copying source code from one project to another is even worse. Use the exact, same compiled class on both sides.

Comment: @tsolakp I am not sure... I think it is still trying to use the `TradeRecord` that is sent from another machine

Comment: AS JB Nizet mentioned make sure you are using the same compiled class in your main program and in your WEB-INF jar file.

Comment: @JBNizet I have experimented with just making a simple runnable project that connects to the same socket and tries to read the record with the class i copied. It worked out in reading the object despite the class despite it being compiled on two different machines. It feels like it might be some kind of configuration with Tomcat that I didn't set up correctly because it cannot find the `TradeRecord` class

Comment: I have also tried just using that plainly compiled `TradeRecord` in my WEB-INF library as well as the external library, but that still showed the same exception... by placing it in Tomcat library, it gave me an error on annotation

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat can't find the `TradeRecord` class because it isn't there. The only 'configuration' required is to put it into the same package at source and destination and include the class in the WAR or one of its dependent JARs in its `lib` directory.